# How to prepend length in little endian

Tags: java, netty

I have a **netty 4.0** based application in which I need to receive/send messages which are prepended with 2-bytes message size in **LITTLE_ENDIAN**.

I figured out the receiving part and I'm receiving messages successfully.

But I can't figure out how to do the same for the *Prepender* which currently adds the length in the default which is **BIG_ENDIAN**. Please advice how can I change this.

```
@Override
public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
    ch.pipeline()
    // Decoder - This part works as expected
    .addLast("frameDecoder", new LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN, 4096 /*maximum length*/, 0 /* size field offset */, 2 /* size field length */, 0, 2, false))
    .addLast("protobufDecoder", new ProtobufDecoder(MoopRrAdmin.AdminResponse.getDefaultInstance(), extensionRegistry))

    // Encoder the Prepender adds length in BIG ENDIAN which is wrong
    .addLast("frameEncoder", new LengthFieldPrepender(2 /* size filed length */, 0 /* length adjustment */, true /* size includes size field */))
    .addLast("protobufEncoder", new ProtobufEncoder())

    // Handler
    .addLast(new MoopConnectionHandler(requester, instanceConnectionManager));
}
```

**EDIT:**

Just to share the temporary solution which actually *works*. The question is still on though since I don't believe this is the intended way ...

```
...
// Encoder
.addLast("frameEncoder", new LengthFieldPrepender(2 /* size filed length */, 0 /* length adjustment */, false /* size includes size field */) {
    @Override
    protected void encode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf msg, ByteBuf out) throws Exception {
        ByteBuf outWithLittleEndian = out.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
        super.encode(ctx, msg, outWithLittleEndian);
    }
})
...
```

Comment: Ugly: override the method `LengthFieldPrepender.encode` call the super instance and reverse the 2 bytes in the out ByteBuf.

Comment: I'm actually trying that right now, but I don't think this is the intended way ... :) But thanks for the tip anyway!

Comment: Actually what I'm trying right now is to call `out.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)` and then calling `super(...)`